# How do I add ads on my published android app?

Tags: android, admob, apk, ads, google-play-console

Hi every one so I published my first app on google play store (without ads) and  after adding Ads code snippet on my app (I used AdMob and already linked my app with my google AdMob).
So now should i generate an other APK and publish it on google play console or is there   any other method to show ads on my app it's already on google play store (without ads)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - no, you can't.

You must need an advertising-id set for your ads (which is unique to every ad). You must need to publish an update to your app with new ads.

You won't lose any of your existing users if you release the update, they will just receive an updated app from google play.